# Visual studio 2015 c++ project error c++11 standard

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2015, compiler-errors

I have a problem with my project when I'm going to compile it. I use visual studio 2015 and the code where the error appears is :

```
template <typename AtomicElement>
class Granule {
public:

typedef spare::Sequence<AtomicElement> RepresentantType;

unsigned int            SymbolID;    // identifier of the symbol
unsigned int                Occurrences; // occurrences of the symbol
spare::RealType                 CompCost;    // compactness cost
spare::RealType                 Cost;        // total cost
spare::RealType                 CardCost;    // cardinality/size cost
spare::RealType             Part;        // index of partition of the symbol
spare::RealType             Clust;       // index of the cluster of the symbol
spare::RealType                 CardClust;   // cardinality of the cluster of the symbol
std::vector<spare::RealType>    ThetaVec;    // vector for theta values

    /*
     * Default constructor
     */
    Granule() {}

    /*
     * Constructor prototype
     */
    Granule(typename spare::Sequence<AtomicElement>& rPrototype,
           spare::RealType  aRecogThreshold,
           spare::RealType  aClusterQuality) {

        if (rPrototype.size()==0) {
            throw std::logic_error("Empty prototype.");
        }

        if ((aRecogThreshold < 0) || (aRecogThreshold > 1)) {
            throw std::logic_error("Invalid DistThreshold.");
        }

        if ((aClusterQuality < 0) || (aClusterQuality > 1)) {
            throw std::logic_error("Invalid ClusterQuality.");
        }

        // Initialization
        mPrototype= rPrototype;
        mRecogThreshold= aRecogThreshold;
        mClusterQuality= aClusterQuality;
    }


    /*
     * Constructor with prototype defined through iterator
     */
    Granule(typename spare::Sequence<AtomicElement>::const_iterator iBegin,
            typename spare::Sequence<AtomicElement>::const_iterator iEnd,
            GdsReal aTheta,
            GdsReal aBeta) {

        if (iBegin >= iEnd) {
            throw std::logic_error("Invalid iterators.");
        }

        if ((aTheta < 0) || (aTheta > 1)) {
            throw std::logic_error("Invalid Theta.");
        }

        if ((aBeta < 0) || (aBeta > 1)) {
            throw std::logic_error("Invalid Beta.");
        }

        // Assign
        mPrototype.assign(iBegin, iEnd);
        mRecogThreshold= aTheta;
        mClusterQuality= aBeta;
    }


    // Prototype definition through iterators
    typename spare::Sequence<AtomicElement>::const_iterator begin() const { return mPrototype.begin(); }

    typename spare::Sequence<AtomicElement>::const_iterator end() const   { return mPrototype.end(); }

    // Prototype size
    typename spare::Sequence<AtomicElement>::size_type  size () const { return mPrototype.size(); }


    // Access to Prototype
    const typename spare::Sequence<AtomicElement>&  Prototype() const       { return mPrototype; }
    // Access to Prototype
    typename spare::Sequence<AtomicElement>&  Prototype()           { return mPrototype; }

    // Access to RecogThreshold
    const spare::RealType&   RecogThreshold() const { return mRecogThreshold; }

    // Access to ClusterQuality
    const spare::RealType&   ClusterQuality() const { return mClusterQuality; }
    // Access to RecogThreshold
    spare::RealType&         RecogThreshold()        { return mRecogThreshold; }

    // Access to ClusterQuality
    spare::RealType&         ClusterQuality()        { return mClusterQuality; }

private:


    // Structure that represents the symbol
    typename spare::Sequence<AtomicElement> mPrototype;

    // Recognition threshold
    spare::RealType                         mRecogThreshold;

    // Symbol quality
    spare::RealType                         mClusterQuality; };

   // Symbols ordering criteria
  template <class StructureType>
  inline bool operator<(const StructureType& S1, const StructureType& S2) {
            return (S1.ClusterQuality() > S2.ClusterQuality());
  }
```

When I compile the error is :

```
error C2039: 'ClusterQuality': is not a member of 'std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<Granule<std::vector<spare::RealType,std::allocator<T>>>>>>'
```

But if I compile the same project on `Dev c++` and use the flag `c++11` I don't have this error.

How can I solve this problem? I have to use visual studio.

Comment: Which line? How do you create a `Granule`?

Comment: Questions like "Why isn't this code working" should have the minimal code necessary to reproduce the problem. Please look into making a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You problem is that your `operator<` is global and too broad. I assume somewhere yo have code that iterates over an vector and compare elements.

```
template <class StructureType>
inline bool operator<(const Granule<StructureType>& S1, const Granule<StructureType>& S2) {
    return (S1.ClusterQuality() > S2.ClusterQuality());
}
```

or similar.

I could reproduce it here https://godbolt.org/g/3AR6kd. I just added

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> t2;

    if (t2.end() < t2.begin())
    {
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suspect your reasoning is correct, although we can't really tell until OP provides a MCVE. As an aside, note that OP's `Granule` class is templated.